# Retrieve an exact word- Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file which contains the same headings for different information. I want to extract the information for one of them. How to do it?

Actually, I want to extract number 234874 from /membership_number="ID:234874 for the person named sarah, but not them same ID from John. Actually, the number can be anything, I just want to extract the number with the condition that I don't know the exact number to use: grep '234874'

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't edit them better than this. They are all together.

Comment: sorry, couldn't do it. The file content is:Information /Name="Sarah"

            /Family_Name="Maryland"
           /membership_number="ID:234874"
Extra Information /Location="Paris"
                        /Age=12
                        /Life=Good
                        /Job="Student"                                     
Information /Name="John"
            /Family_Name="Smith"
           /membership_number="ID:290473"
Extra Information /Location="Berlin"
                        /Age=34
                        /Life=Not bad
                        /Job="Doctor"

Comment: I put your comment into your question. Now please add which word you like to use for selecting the right line and what output you like.

Comment: Actually, I want to extract number 234874 from /membership_number="ID:234874 for the person named sarah, but not them same ID from John. Actually, the number can be anything, I just want to extract the number with the condition that I don't know the exact number to use: grep '234874'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -v '^$' <filename> | awk '/Information \/Name="Sarah"/ {getline; getline; print $1}' | cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d '"'
```

Here:

`grep -v '^$' <filename>`: This removes the blank lines.

`awk '/Information \/Name="Sarah"/ {getline; getline; print $1}'`: This finds the name and gets the membership line.

`cut -d':' -f2 | tr -d '"'`: This fetches the exact number.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Can you please come to my new question? I have put the actual data in it for better clarification. Tq. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030149/how-to-extract-geneid-from-ncbi-unix

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
grep -E "Name=\"Sarah\"" inputfile | grep -Eo "membership_number=\"[^\"]*" | cut -d: -f2
```

or put things together with

```
sed -n 's/.*Name="Sarah".*membership_number="ID:\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' inputfile
```